# The ggplot theme assist add in for R keeps showing extremely small window so I cant see anything

Tags: r, ggplot2, add-in

Somewhat self explanatory. No matter what dataset I run, which libraries I have, etc. I keep having this happen when I run the theme assist add in for R:

[image]

This is at least semi-visible but often I can't see anything when I'm making bar graphs and such, so if there is a quick fix to this issue I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question relates to an issue the user is having running an add in, rather than a problem about coding.  [The question should be posted as an issue in gitHub](https://github.com/calligross/ggthemeassist).

Comment: Im actually not sure why this belongs in gitHub. You can certainly let me know why I'm wrong about that, but I've only ever used stackoverflow for these kinds of questions. Given that its a package in R still, it still counts to me as coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out an answer. I tried repeatedly to just use the "ctrl +" command in the **actual theme assistant window** to no avail.

What I did after was exit out of the theme assistant altogether and then minimized the screen several times with "ctrl -" in the **script area**. It is now far more visible, though at the expense of the script looking super tiny.

[image: Fixed add in]

Now it is far more visible!

Hopefully this is helpful if anybody else runs into this problem. Took me longer than it should have to figure this out, but didn't seem to have any clear answers elsewhere.